# Why isn't a down voted question moved to the top of the front page after editing one of its answers?

Tags: support, editing, down-votes

I edited [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143363/why-is-yoda-so-useless) question's answer, but it was not bumped to the top of the front page like a normal post would.

I can only assume that down voted questions are not put at the top for some reason. So why is this?

Answer (score 7):

The question currently has a score of -13, so [its score is too low to be bumped to the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/299342):

> Questions with sufficiently low score will *not* be bumped when either they or their answers are edited. The "sufficiently low" threshold is -4 on SO and new SE sites, and -8 on MetaSO (as of [Aug 25, '10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62261/are-edited-questions-no-longer-bumped-to-the-front-page/62262#62262) -- see Grace Note's comment).

I'm not aware of an explanation on Meta.SE why this is, but presumably it is to avoid cluttering up the front page with low-quality questions.